# Only plotting objects if they have moved a certain distance in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have code that plots the objects in a 3D scatter graph. Some objects move, so I have a color scale to show which ones move further than the others. Is there a way I can only show the objects that have moved a certain distance, and ignore the ones that haven't (i.e. they don't show up on plot)?

This is the code that I have written:

```
filename= 'testing.gif'
FigHandle = figure('Position', [50, -30, 1000, 800]);

for i=1:1001      
    s=1;
    scatter3(am.data(:,3,i),am.data(:,4,i),am.data(:,5,i),s,am.data(:,6,i))
    colorbar
    caxis([0,2.863])
    % axis([0 50 0 50 0 40]);
    T(i)=getframe
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, you want to compare displacements with respect to the initial position.  These are already encapsulated in the 6th column of your data.  Should any not pass a threshold, you would mark these co-ordinates as `NaN` so they don't show up on the plot.  In other words, given a threshold `thresh` (in your comments, this is `2.863`), do something like this:

```
filename= 'testing.gif'
FigHandle = figure('Position', [50, -30, 1000, 800]);
s = 1;

thresh = 2.863; %// Adjust if necessary

for i = 1:1001
    currentCoords = am.data(:,3:6,i); %// Get current co-ordinates
    %// Find distance between these co-ordinates and the initial ones
    %// that don't pass the threshold and set to NaN
    loc = currentCoords(:,4) <= thresh;
    currentCoords(loc,:) = NaN;

    %// Now plot the data
    scatter3(currentCoords(:,1), currentCoords(:,2) currentCoords(:,3), ...
             s, currentCoords(:,4));

    colorbar;
    caxis([0,2.863]);
    axis([0 50 0 50 0 50]); %// Restrict axes to ensure they don't change
                            %// when plotting each frame
    T(i)=getframe;
end
```

---

## Edit - September 5th, 2014

Now that you have grabbed the frames for each of the scatter plots, you want to write these to file.  That can very easily be accomplished using the [`VideoWriter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter-class.html) class.  You just have to set up the video writer, and it takes in a `frame` structure.  You have already collected these with the `T` variable.  As such, the next thing you need to do is set up the characteristics of your video, such as what codec you want to use, what frame rate and so on.  You would create a video writer like this:

```
filename_video = 'out.mp4'; %// or 'out.avi';
codec_name = 'MPEG-4';
videoWriter = VideoWriter(filename_video, codec_name);
videoWriter.FrameRate = 20; %// Set frame rate here
videoWriter.Quality = 100; %// Set quality of each frame here
```

You need to read the documentation on what codecs are supported with MATLAB that you can write files to, but `MPEG-4` is very popular and it works on Windows 7 systems and up as well as Mac OS X 10.7 or later.  If you want to save in an `AVI` container, you can certainly do that, but make sure you specify the right codec for this purpose.  The first two lines of the above code specifies the output file name of the video you want to save, as well as the codec you want to use.  The next three lines after set up the video writer, and sets the frame rate and the quality of each frame if you are using a lossy codec.  For lossless, the quality setting won't do anything.  There are a whole bunch of other parameters you can set to customize what your video will look like, but I'll leave that to you to read the documentation on figuring this out.  To get basic video working, the above is sufficient.

What you need to do next is open up the file for writing, then loop through each of your frames in `T` and write the frames to this video.  After you're done, you close the video.  In other words, you do this next:

```
open(videoWriter); %// Open the video writer
for idx = 1 : numel(T)  %// Write the frames to file
    writeVideo(videoWriter, T(idx));
end
close(videoWriter); %// Close the video writer
```

If it all works out, you will see a `.mp4` (or `.avi`) file saved where you ran this code and you should be able to view it using any conventional video viewing software (like [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/)). 
  I can't stress enough that you need to **open** the file for writing, and when you're done you **close** the file.  No video will be saved until you close the file.

Good luck!

Comment: I dont think it is yet right. The current coords - why is it (:,3:6,i)? I do not know why this. We do not need to subtract displacements. It is already total displacement. Does this make sense? Also, is the ... just signify next line? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Also, when I run it, I just get one frame - It should be generating a movie. I just get a frame with all the objects.

Comment: @JacksonHart - I'm probably misinterpreting what you mean by total displacement.  Is this already with respect to the initial position?  That means I don't even need to keep track of the first position.  In your code, you use `scatter3` and you accessed the third to sixth columns independently.  I just decided to vectorize this to make this easier.  Yes, `...` means to continue to the next line.  This is valid MATLAB syntax.

Comment: Correct, we do not need initial position. It is implicit in displacement column. The idea is to create a movie showing only displaced objects. So each frame should have more and more displaced objects as time progresses.

Comment: @JacksonHart - Fantastic.  I'll edit once more.  I also don't know why you're not getting more than one frame.  I'll double-check my code.

Comment: Why do we start at 2 and not 1?

Comment: @JacksonHart - Ignore that.  That's going to change.  You're right in that it had to do with the initial co-ordinates.  Since we aren't dealing with that anymore, the loop will go back to starting at 1.

Comment: Ok, I was figuring it had something to do with initial coordinates

Comment: You have completely answered! Can I ask one more question? The axes keep changing, when I moved the axis statement inside if statement though, it makes 1000 figures, which I dont want. any suggestions?

Comment: @JacksonHart - Cool!  Can you be more specific? What're you trying to do?  I don't quite understand what you said in your statement.

Comment: The way I want it, each figure overwrites the previous one, but the variable T stores each one. Then at the end, I combine images to make a movie. However, the movie looks bad because as the objects move, the axes change some. Like it will be xlim (0 40) but object will move and limits x-axis changes to say, (0,45). Is there a way to fix this? The way it is written does not work for some reason. If I move the axes{(xlo xhi ...]) statement inside if statement, i get 1000 figures

Comment: @JacksonHart - Do you want the axes to stay the same when you draw it?  Simply place an `axis()` statement before you call `getframe` to make sure the limits don't change.  What should the range of the `x`, `y` and `z` axes be?

Comment: @JacksonHart - That `axis` call you have made in your code that you commented out should work when you uncomment it.  You're saying that it generates 1000 figures when you do this?

Comment: Do you know if they have any markertypes that are spheres instead of circles? I cant find any markertype that is 3D

Comment: @JacksonHart - Unfortunately no :( You're only limited to the same markers that appear in 2D plots (cross, star, circle, square, etc.).

Comment: @rayryreng Hey, do you know how to save T as video and change fps rate>

Comment: @JacksonHart Yeah I'll write an answer soon.

Comment: @JacksonHart - Done.  Good luck!